# Using dplyr::filter on two variables with a negation

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter out rows in a data table that match two conditions. 
I tried the following, but that drops all the rows with either one of the two conditions.

```
filter(starwars, hair_color != "none" && eye_color != "black")
```

It must be simple, but I don't see it.
Help would be appreciated

Cheers
Renger

Comment: Try `&` instead of `&&`: `filter(starwars, hair_color != "none" & eye_color != "black") `

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to read when you first specify the group you want to exclude, then exclude it:

```
filter(starwars, !(hair_color == "none" & eye_color == "black"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are trying to filter conditions that match both conditions or either

If you are trying to drop rows that match both conditions use:

```
   starwars%>% filter( ! hair_color != "none" & eye_color != "black")
```

if you are trying to drop rows that have one condition OR the other use:

```
   starwars%>% filter( ! hair_color != "none" | eye_color != "black")
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing filtering steps the AND and OR are really confusing.

You should use | instead of & to get what you want:

`starwars%>% filter( hair_color != "none" | eye_color != "black")`

This is due to how logical statements work. AND searches for both strings indepently and drops all where a statement is true, while for OR the statements has to be true for both statements (select only those where A and B is true). This confuses me all the time but this is how 'logic' works. It helps when you look at a venn diagram and really make an example.

In the end, I prefer the solution scoa gave as it is more intuitive.