How to filter data based on values of row above in R
I am trying to filter out rows based on conditions of a given row as well as the row above it. Here is a sample dataset:
points <- c(1:18)
travel <- c(1, 5, 200, 400, 15, 30, 400, 402, 8, 17, 52, 41, 600, 580, 5, 12, 180, 0)
angle <- c(0, -30, 55, 3, -160, 108, -172, -180, -5, 42, -86, 160, -3, 164, 16, -30, 84, 0)

path <- data.frame(points, travel, angle)

I want to remove a row only if all of the following conditions are met:

travel in a given row, say row "i", >100 AND
travel in the row above row i, say row "i-1", >100 AND
angle in row "i" > abs(150)

For this scenario, I want to remove rows 8 and 14

It's similar, but I don't think that one involves negation / "remove if any of multiple tests met." I suspect there's a better match out there, but I couldn't find it yet.

Yes, there’s 3 components of this question (lag being the 3rd), all of which have been answered before here somewhere, but hard to find due to incorrect tags.

I suggested https://stackoverflow.com/q/48505296/6851825 as a better match for the "multiple matches with negation" part.

filter specifies what we want to keep, so it sounds like we can use OR operator | to specify the three different ways that would include a row. This will exclude only the rows for which the opposite test is true in all three cases.
path |>
  filter(travel <= 100 | lag(travel) <= 100 | abs(angle) <= 150)

Or we could use the & AND for the three tests, and use the ! negation operator on their combination.
path |>
  filter(!(travel > 100 & lag(travel) > 100 & abs(angle) > 150))

Result
   points travel angle
1       1      1     0
2       2      5   -30
3       3    200    55
4       4    400     3
5       5     15  -160
6       6     30   108
7       7    400  -172
8       9      8    -5
9      10     17    42
10     11     52   -86
11     12     41   160
12     13    600    -3
13     15      5    16
14     16     12   -30
15     17    180    84
16     18      0     0

